# Querying Tableau Server for exporting a view using python and REST API

Tags: python, automation, tableau-api, export-to-csv, tableau-desktop

I am trying to export a tableau view as an image/csv (doesn't matter) using Python. I googled and found that REST API would help here, so I created a Personal Access Token and wrote the following command to connect: -

```
import tableauserverclient as TSC
from tableau_api_lib import TableauServerConnection
from tableau_api_lib.utils.querying import get_views_dataframe, get_view_data_dataframe

server_url = 'https://tableau.mariadb.com'
site = ''
mytoken_name = 'Marine'
mytoken_secret = '$32mcyTOkmjSFqKBeVKEZYpMUexseV197l2MuvRlwHghMacCOa'

server = TSC.Server(server_url, use_server_version=True)
tableau_auth = TSC.PersonalAccessTokenAuth(token_name=mytoken_name, personal_access_token=mytoken_secret, site_id=site)
with server.auth.sign_in_with_personal_access_token(tableau_auth):
    print('[Logged in successfully to {}]'.format(server_url))
```

It entered successfully and gave the message: -

```
[Logged in successfully to https://tableau.mariadb.com]
```

However, Iam at a loss now on how to access the tableau workbooks using Python. I searched here:-

https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_ref_workbooks_and_views.htm

but was unable to write these commands like GET or others in python.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You should not post your token information. if you're going to use the tableau_api_lib, then check out their docs. https://pypi.org/project/tableau-api-lib/

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you don't know the view_id of the view you're looking for

Adding this after the print in the with block will query all the views available on your site;

```
 all_views, pagination_item = server.views.get()
 print([view.name for view in all_views])
```

Then find the view you're looking for in the printed output and note the view_id for use like this;

```
view_item = server.view.get_by_id('d79634e1-6063-4ec9-95ff-50acbf609ff5')
```

From there, you can get the image like this;

```
server.views.populate_image(view_item)
with open('./view_image.png', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(view_item.image)
```

The tableauserverclient-python docs should help you out a ton as well

https://tableau.github.io/server-client-python/docs/api-ref#views